# Proving that the radical of an ideal is an ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, radicals

[image]

I'm trying to solve problem 1.18 in Fulton's 'Algebraic Curves', which is illustrated in the attached image, but I'm having some difficulties understanding the first part.

The ring R is assumed to be commutative and unital, so the first thing that came to mind was to consider the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^{n+m}$, but I don't see why powers of $a$ which are less than n, or powers of $b$ which are less than m should be contained in the ideal.

An explanation as to how I can show that $Rad(I) $ contains $a+b$ would be appreciated, particularly I'd like to know if one can indeed be guaranteed the containment (in I) of the aforementioned terms from the binomial expansion.

I suspect that I may be missing or forgetting some ring theoretic fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is that in the binomial expansion you have a sum of products $a^ib^{n+m-i}$ with $0 \le i \le n+m$. So either $i\ge n$ in which case $a^i \in I$ or $n+m-i\ge m$ in which case $b^{n+m-i}$. In both cases $a^ib^{n+m-i} \in I$.

Comment: I'm reminded yet again that one shouldn't be lazy in ones thinking. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose, for instance, that $m=3$ and that $n=2$. Then$$(a+b)^{m+n}=(a+b)^5=a^5+5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5ab^4+b^5.$$Then $a^5$, $a^4b$, $a^3b^2$ and $a^2b^3$ all belong to $I$, since $a^2$ does. And $ab^4$ and $b^5$ also belong to $I$, since $b^3$ does. Therefore, $(a+b)^5\in I$.